# How to create a viewer field for relay in django-graphene root schema?

Tags: django, reactjs, graphene-python, relaymodern, react-relay

How to create a viewer field for react-relay in graphene-django? 
This does not work like intended. I am using graphene-django v.2.2. Django 2.1. React-relay v1.7.0-rc.1.

```
// landingpage.schema.py

class CollectionNode(DjangoObjectType):
  class Meta:
    model = Collection
    interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Viewer(graphene.ObjectType):
  class Meta:
    interfaces = [relay.Node, ]

  collection = graphene.Field(CollectionNode)

  def resolve_collection(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Collection.objects.all()


class Query(object):
  viewer = graphene.Field(Viewer)

  def resolve_viewer(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Viewer() # or info.parent_type
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem myself. So I moved the viewer object to the root schema like this. Hope this can help anybody else who has the same problem.

```
// project_name.schema.py

import graphene
import graphql_jwt
from django.conf import settings
from graphene import relay, ObjectType

import about.schema
import shop.schema
import landingpage.schema

class Viewer(about.schema.Query, landingpage.schema.Query, shop.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
  class Meta:
    interfaces = [relay.Node, ]

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  viewer = graphene.Field(Viewer)

  def resolve_viewer(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Viewer() # or info.parent_type

class Mutation(shop.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
  token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
  verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
  refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

_

```
// landingpage.schema.py

class CollectionNode(DjangoObjectType):
  class Meta:
    model = Collection
    interfaces = (relay.Node, )

# 
#  QUERY

class Query(object):
  class Meta:
    interfaces = [relay.Node, ]

  collection = graphene.Field(CollectionNode)

  def resolve_collection(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Collection.objects.all()
```

Comment: Why is this not in either of the cookbook examples or in the django-graphene documentation?

Comment: I do not know. Hope this helped you.